# import cannot be resolved for selenium drivers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to import WebDriver & ChromeDriver, tried all libraires but no luck

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/vikas/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");

        // Initialize browser
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();


        // Open Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Maximize browser

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

Getting below errors

```
The import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver cannot be resolved
The import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver cannot be resolved
```

Comment: @Pradeep It is simple Core Java project and not using pom or maven. Do I need to create web app project?

Comment: @Pradeep Yes I can see them

Comment: I was having a similar kind of error in VS code but I changed my python version that I was using in VS code which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

selenium jar has to be added to the project to identify the interface `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` and class `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver`

selenium download link: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: Should I import entire lib folder?

Comment: Yes import all jar files. Importing all jar files will help you resolve other issues. Also, chromedriver which you use specific to windows (.exe), download linux specific chromedriver then use it in your system property

Comment: Awesome...Yes I did it and works. Thanks and keep up good work.

Comment: Thats exatcly what I said to download with jars

Answer (score 1):

Remove the selenium java jar files from Modulepath and add to Classpath

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer is more of a comment, which you unfortunately don't have enough reputation for. Check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for inspiration or take the [tour]. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to unresolved dependency.
can you confirm if all your jar dependencies are resolved

Comment: I know the reason but can you please provide relevant jars?

Comment: for org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver jar you can try http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumjava20b1jar.htm

Comment: for org.openqa.selenium.chrome.chromedriver you can try http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadseleniumchromedriver20a4jar.htm

Answer (score 0):

You are working on Linux/Mac, as you have a path like `/home/vikas/`, but you are using chromedriver.exe.

You can't use exe binary on Linux platform. It is specifically designed for Windows only, `.exe` is only for Windows.

You need to download Linux/Mac chrome binary from below URL:

https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/

Comment: Yes I have got it from above link but what extension should I keep then?

Comment: The extention should be as same as file binary have. if it don't have don't mention it .. keep it chormedriver only

Comment: Ok it is simply chromedriver but still import problem is there

Comment: have you added selenium server and client jars in you build path?

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue unresolved dependency. I think you should to used [selenium 3.4](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) with [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) 2.32 and chrome 60 browser

Also i guess uu are importing all the jar files

Answer (score 0):

The recommended Selenium (and chromedriver) that you must to use depends on your Chrome Browser version.

If you are using the latest version of the Chrome Browser, you have to use the [latest chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.33/) and (is recommended to) import the **Selenium 3.5 (or greater)**.

So, from [selenium download](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/), download your interested version and import the jar in your project.

If is a maven project, you can simple add this dependency on your pom:

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

Else download the .jar and import manually (find how to import a jar using your IDE).

Answer (score 0):

If it is in mac, there should be problem in setProperty path. Instead of mentioning chromedriver.exe, you should give just chromedriver(as you should be seeing just chromedriver under Downloads).

Be sure to set JAVA_HOME path in bash profile.

Answer (score 0):

When adding external jars, make sure you add the jars in the lib folder first before adding the ones in the main selenium-java folder. This made the difference for me.